# How to change timepicker value to another timepicker value?

Tags: javascript, ajax, timepicker

my web has 2 timepicker input and I want to change 2nd timepicker input to 1st value after it changed. 
here are my code and it doesnt work

```
<script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#team_date" ).datepicker({
                    'dateFormat':'yy-mm-dd',
                    'changeMonth': true,
                    'changeYear': true
                });
                $( "#team_start_time" ).timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s', 'step' : 1 });
                $( "#team_stop_time" ).timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s', 'step' : 1 });
                $( "#show_stop_time" ).timepicker({ 'timeFormat': 'H:i:s', 'step' : 1 });
            });

            $("#team_stop_time").timepicker({

            onSelect: function(date, instance) {

                  $("#show_stop_time").timepicker.val() = $("#team_stop_time").timepicker.val();
             }
            });
</script>
```

ps.change from datepicker tot timepicker. sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onSelect: function(date, instance) {
    $("#show_stop_time").datepicker.( "setDate", date );
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
[reference](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field)

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
altField: "#show_stop_time",
altFormat: "H:i:s"
});
});
```

Comment: ok you want to use a timepicker then how you use datepicker()

Answer (score 0):

Solve

```
    <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.datepair.js"></script>

    .
    .
    .

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#ppp .time').timepicker({
    'showDuration': true,
    'timeFormat': 'H:i:s'
    });

    $('#ppp').datepair();

</script>
```